# Change all button style with theming

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

I want to change all button style, without having to add style one after another like that:

`<Button mode="contained" style={{ backgroundColor: "#FF6766" }} >`

I'm trying to do something with that:

```
const theme = {
  ...DefaultTheme,
  roundness: 2,
  colors: {
    ...DefaultTheme.colors,
    primary: '#ffffff',
    accent: '#f1c40f',
    text: '#515151',
    surface: '#FF6766',
    underlineColor: 'transparent',
    background: '#ffffff',
    contained: '#000000',
  }
};
```

But I don't know if it's possible here, I found this on this link:  https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/theming.html

App.js

```
export default function App() {

  const theme = {
    ...DefaultTheme,
    roundness: 2,
    colors: {
      ...DefaultTheme.colors,
      primary: '#ffffff',
      accent: '#f1c40f',
      text: '#515151',
      surface: '#FF6766',
      underlineColor: 'transparent',
      background: '#ffffff',
      contained: '#000000',
    }
  };

  return (
    <PaperProvider theme={theme}>
      <AppNavigator />
    </PaperProvider>
  )

}
```

Comment: Did you pass this theme to `PaperProvider` like in the docs ? `<PaperProvider theme={theme}>`

Comment: @adesurirey yes look my edit please

Comment: That should work, as long as you're importing components from `react-native-paper` and not `react-native`. What's your current issue with it?

Comment: @zaytrix for exemple I can't change background colour buttons

Comment: The color set as `primary` will change the background color of buttons with `mode='contained'`